# How to close the inside face of a gear

Tags: mesh

I created this gear (from the Blender additional meshes add-on), and I would like to fill the gap to make the inside like the inside of a cylinder:

[image]

I tried selecting the edges and typing <kbd>F</kbd> but that filled the top and bottom faces:

[image]

I added a cylinder inside the gear and tried <kbd>F</kbd> again but no success here either:

[image]

[image]

Not sure how to do this...

Blend:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the rings on the top and bottom have the same number of vertices, you can select the top and bottom edges, then press the space bar and type **[bridge edge loops](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html?highlight=bridge#bridge-edge-loops)**:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! I always forget about this function... Not sure what the difference between Fill and Bridge Edge Loops is... Or why it's not combined into one!

Comment: They are two very different tools fill will make a face (most likely an Ngon) connecting all selected vertices. Bridge will make quads connecting two edge loops that have the same number of vertices.

Comment: @fabriced please read the link that is part of the answer (in blue letters). You'll see the tools at your disposal.